# Could not find property on project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to use the Grgit plugin, and I want to reference `Grgit` from a separate `gradle` file.

Gradle is able to find `Grgit` when I try it like this:

***./build.gradle:***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:0.8.+'
    }
}

import org.ajoberstar.grgit.*

def repo = Grgit.open(".")
```

However, when I move the two last lines to a separate `file.gradle`, like below, it doesn't work:

***./build.gradle:***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:0.8.+'
    }
}

apply from: 'file.gradle'
```

***./file.gradle:***

```
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.*

def repo = Grgit.open(".")
```

---

The error shown:

```
Could not find property 'Grgit' on root project 'MyProject'.
```

How can I use `Grgit` in a separate file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to move the `buildscript` block to `file.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Do you know why this isn't implicitly used from `build.gradle`?

Comment: Currently, `buildscript` blocks only propagate from parent projects to child projects, but not from projects to applied scripts.